# How to delete a component created by a template reference?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to get a reference to a component that was generated from a template so I can manually destroy it later on. Is this possible?

In this example I have a template, I am then using `createEmbeddedView` to create a new instance, then adding it to the current view. This works how I intend it to.

I have tried to and the ability to delete `my-component`, but I am not sure how to access it. I know I can access the component directly with `@ViewChildren()`, but how do I get a `ComponentRef` for that component and destroy it so it is removed from the DOM?

```js
@Component({
  template: `
  <button (click)="open()"></button>

  <ng-template #template let-message="message">
    <my-component>{{message}}</my-component>
  </ng-template>
  `
})
export ExampleComponent {

  @ViewChild('template')
  template!: TemplateRef<object>;

  @ViewChildren(MyComponent)
  myComponents!: QueryList<MyComponent>;

  constructor(
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
  ){ }

  open() {
    const template = this.template.createEmbeddedView({message: 'hello'});
    this.viewContainerRef.insert(template);
  }
}
```

### Works if deleted from last to first

I was able to get it working using `remove()`, however is this a good way to do it?

```js
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.myComponents.changes.subscribe(() => {
      this.myComponents.forEach((cmp, idx) => {
        if (!cmp.isOpen) {
          cmp.open();
          let sub = cmp.closed.subscribe(() => {
            this.viewContainerRef.remove(idx);
            sub.unsubscribe();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just revert `this.viewContainerRef.insert(template)` with `this.viewContainerRef.remove(0)` or `this.viewContainerRef.remove(this.viewContainerRef.length - 1)`. This will unmount the component and free memory as there will be no reference left (`const template` is scoped to the `open` function)

Comment: That deletes everything I only want to delete one. So, if I click on the button 3 times and delete one, `clear()` will delete them all.

Comment: Oh OK then use `this.viewContainerRef.remove(0)` or `this.viewContainerRef.remove(this.viewContainerRef.length - 1)`

Comment: Got it: `this.myComponents.forEach((cmp, idx) => this.viewContainerRef.remove(idx))`

Comment: This deletes everything just like `clear()`?

Comment: OK, glad you made it!

Comment: See my updates to the question, is that a good approach?

Comment: Actually looking at it, if I delete the middle item (of 3), the index might be out of bounds when deleting the last item.

Comment: Yeah because of the closure.

Comment: I'd try with `createComponent` instead of `createEmbeddedView` because your template contains nothing else than `my-component`, then notify the parent of the close event with `this` as parameter and retrieve the actual index of the component to remove with `this.viewContainerRef.indexOf(event)`